# Convert JSON result to object type

Tags: c#

When I run the below code I am getting an error stating

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    var res = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(res.ToString());
    JObject ojObject = (JObject)joResponse["result"]; --> This line is throwing error
    string ticketnumber = ((JValue)ojObject.SelectToken("number")).Value.ToString();

    return ticketnumber;
}
```

I tried converting it to type Object below way but getting error

```
JObject ojObject = (JObject)joResponse["result"].ToObject(JObject));
```

My 3rd party API returns data in the below format and in c# i need to get the value of number field i.e "IM3423354"

```
{
  "import_set": "ISET0010001",
  "staging_table": "imp_user",
  "result": [
    {
      "transform_map": "User",
      "table": "sys_user",
      "display_name": "number",
      "display_value": "IM3423354",
      "record_link": "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/ea928be64f411200adf9f8e18110c777",
      "status": "inserted", 
      "sys_id": "ea928be64f411200adf9f8e18110c777"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You could [use a debugger and inspect the variable](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) where the error occurs?

Comment: Please include the JSON which you are trying to parse.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith updated my post

Comment: Why are you trying to treat an array as an object? Just use `JArray result = (JArray) joResponse["result"];` You can then take the first object *in* that array if you want to.

Comment: I tried this : string ticketnumber = ((JValue)objObject[0].SelectToken("number")).value.ToString();  and also string ticketnumber = ojObject[0].SelectToken("number").ToString() and in both the cases i got object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are trying to access result as an object, but it is actually an array containing a single object.  So you need to do this to get the object.

```
JToken ojObject = joResponse["result"][0];
```

But there is another problem, in that there is no field called `number` in your JSON.  I think the value you want is actually in a field called `display_value`.  So then you also need to use this.

```
string ticketnumber = ((JValue)ojObject.SelectToken("display_value")).Value.ToString();
```

You can even shorten this to the following;

```
string ticketnumber = (string)joResponse.SelectToken("result[0].display_value");
```